# $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2m}$ is factorized by 2n+1

Tags: number-theory

For natural number m,
$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2m}$ is factorized by 2n+1. Is it proved?
To be exact, I want to know this is true for all m like this :
$m=1, \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$
So this formula is factorized by 2n+1.
I see that is true for $m=1,2,3,4,5$. Is it true for all m?

Comment: Who is $m$? Because if I was free, it would be false taking $n=m=2$.

Comment: I mean that : for m=1, $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$. So it is factored by 2n+1. I see the factorized formula for $m = 1, 2, ... , 5$, all the formula have 2n+1 factor.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make much sense.  If $n=m=3$ then   $1 + 2^6 + 3^6 =794$ which is not divisibly by $7$ and there isn't any reason to think it would be.  So I probably don't understand what you are asking.  What are you asking.

Comment: I editted what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is closely related to Faulhaber polynomials, you can find interesting reading in these articles [arxiv.org/pdf/2103.08553](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.08553.pdf),  [ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1197512-7/S0025-5718-1993-1197512-7.pdf) and [researchgate.net/publication/Faulhaber_polynomials](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351137196_Faulhaber_polynomials) where you can find the following form for powers of odd exponents:
Let $S_m=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^m$ and $N=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, then
$$S_{2m+1}=a_1N^2+a_2N^3+a_3N^4+\dots+a_mN^{m+1}$$
Then

$$
S_{2m}=\frac{2n+1}{2(2m+1)}( 2a_1N+3a_2N^2+4a_3N^3+\dots+(m+1)a_mN^{m})
$$
Hence
$$
S_{2m}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2(2m+1)}( 2a_1+3a_2N+4a_3N^2+\dots+(m+1)a_mN^{m-1}).
$$
Actually with a little more effort we can prove that $\color{red}{\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}}$ divide $S_{odd>1}$ and $\color{red}{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}$ divide $S_{even}$.

Answer (score 0):

I claim it is true for all $m$

First, notice

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2m} mod (2n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n (k-(2n+1))^{2m} mod (2n+1) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k^{2m} mod (2n+1) $$

Since $(k-2n-1)^{2m}=(2n+1-k)^{2m}$, because the exponent is even

Then we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^{2m} mod (2n+1)= 2 \sum_{k=1}^n k^{2m} mod (2n+1) $$

So we just need to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^{2m} mod (2n+1)=0$

This is a subset of cases where $\sum_{k=1}^p k^{q} mod (p+1)=0$

Where $p=2n, q=2m$ in this case. We can prove this with induction! (Note I will prove in for all positive integers p, and q, which will make it true for our sub-case as well)

Base case $q=1$ clearly works, the base case is satisfied

I know this is true for even numbers as linked here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

but I'm not sure about even, especially higher ones. I'll check it out but this is the most complete solution I can give right now